# Distributed List on Redis cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I'm using a Redis cluster version 6.2 with N master nodes.

I am using a Redis `list` as a *queue*. The number of entries in the *queue* is quite large, i.e. more than 10s of millions, each of size ~1KB.

The problem is that entire *queue* data is managed by a single master node. And the memory usage of the owner master node is very skewed compared to the other master nodes.

Is there any way to distributed this *queue* data over all the master nodes available in the cluster?